# How do I prevent my exe4j executable being flagged as Bloodhound trojan by Symantec Endpoint?

Tags: install4j, symantec, exe4j

I created a java application and wrapped it in executable using exe4j version 5, but every time I start the executable the symantec endpoint protection 12 quadrant the exe file because it thinks the executable is bloodhound Trojan. But this problem does not exist if I create the executable with exe4j version 2 or less.

Same issue happened if I used install4j to create install package.

Is there is any settings need to be done to exe4j or install4j project to fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

This is a false positive. Unfortunately this happens from time to time. You can report this to the anti-virus software vendor, they all accept false positives reports. Usually, this is then fixed with the next update of their virus definitions.

Comment: I think the outdated virus definition is the reason, because my Symantec endpoint protection 12 has a problem to update its virus definition, and I do not have this problem with version 11. Thanks for your reply